# Вывести контент поста на главную страницу с сохранением его форматирования

Tags: wordpress

Требуется, чтобы пост с id 81 выводился в определенном месте на главной странице. Содержание поста может быть изменено пользователем. Пост должен выводиться весь (полностью) и с сохранением форматирования (т.е. с разделением на абзацы, пункты, с различным шрифтом и т.п.)

Вывод поста на главной странице удалось реализовать с помощью следующего кода, добавленного в нужное место в файле index.php:

```
<?php
$id = 81; 
$post = get_post($id);
$content = $post->post_content;
echo $post->post_content;
?>
```

Большая просьба помочь доработать код так, чтобы содержание поста не выводилось одним сплошным текстом, как сейчас, а с сохранением форматирования.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $my_postid = 472;
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid); ?>
<?php $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
echo $content; ?>
```

Вот